# Improve code on Getting last split secction

Tags: c#

maybe using the latest technologies, in 3.5 SP1, is there a way to short this?

```
// Bruno: add the empty row with column names
// -- select [CRM5].[USERGROUP].[UserGroup_id], [CRM5].[USERGROUP].[name] AS [name]
if (col.ToLower().Contains("] as ["))
{
   // [CRM5].[USERGROUP].[name] AS [name]
   splitColumn.Clear();    // clear the list
   splitColumn.AddRange(col.Trim().Split(' '));
   emptyRow.Append(String.Format(" '' AS {0},", splitColumn[splitColumn.Count - 1]));
}
else
{
   // [CRM5].[USERGROUP].[UserGroup_id]
   splitColumn.Clear();    // clear the list
   splitColumn.AddRange(col.Trim().Split('.'));
   emptyRow.Append(String.Format(" '' AS {0},", splitColumn[splitColumn.Count - 1]));
```

}

In other words, is there a way to retrieve the last element of a String when split?

maybe

```
col.Trim().Split('.').Find(x => x.LastItem);
```

> col is a String
>
> splitColumn is a List < String >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you've imported System.Linq:

```
var lastOrNull = "".Split(' ').LastOrDefault();
```

To elaborating the above code snippet... this do the trick:

```
col = (col ?? "").Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 
    int.MaxValue, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .LastOrDefault();

if (col != null)
{ 
    emptyRow.Append(String.Format(" '' AS {0},", col);
}
```

Trim() is unnecessary if you specify StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries. The above code will not throw if the string is null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string last = col.Split('.').Last();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the split result array for other reasons, I would consider using col.lastindexof('.') in combination with the substring method.

Due to the -1 that is return if the '.' is not found:

```
col.substring(col.lastindexof('.')+1)
```